# Custom Authorizationhandler for token evaluation that is done externally

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

When the user submits his credentials to my api, I call an external api to authenticate the user. After that, a token gets generated on the external api and will be sent to me. For that I implemented the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` function from the `AuthenticationHandler`:

```
protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
{
    //before this: make call to external api to get the access token
    var claims = new[] {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, submittedToken),
    };
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

    return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
}
```

I have implemented a custom `AuthorizationHandler` which I want to check for the access token that you got when you successfully authenticate. Note that the actual authentication and authorization is done by an external api which is a custom implementation. Here is the function:

```
public class IsAuthorizedRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<IsAuthorizedRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public AuthenticateHandlerHelperFunctions AuthenticateHandlerHelper;

    public IsAuthorizedRequirement()
    {
        AuthenticateHandlerHelper = new AuthenticateHandlerHelperFunctions();
    }
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IsAuthorizedRequirement requirement)
    {
        if(!context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name))
        {
            context.Fail();
            return;
        }

        var token = context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            context.Fail();
            return;
        }

        var checkedToken = await AuthenticateHandlerHelper.CheckAccessToken(token);
        if (checkedToken == null)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return;
        }

        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
}
```

The `CheckAccessToken` function makes a simple HTTP Post Request to the external Api where I get back if the token is still valid or not. Is this a valid implementation especially when multiple users are using this? Especially the claims that I use: Are they created for each user or will the content inside `ClaimsType.Name` be overwritten each time a user makes a request? Currently I have no way to test this so I just wanted to know if I am on the right track for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Is this a valid implementation especially when multiple users are using this?
```

I strongly stand against this approach. Implementation like this mean you would call external API for validate and generate token(or cookie or any form of authenticated certificate) on external server for each and any of your request(which require authentication).

It's could be consider acceptable if we have some special cases on just some endpoints. But for the whole API/Web server. Please don't use this approach.

```
Especially the claims that I use: Are they created for each user or will the content inside ClaimsType.Name be overwritten each time a user makes a request?
```

They'll create for each request. As I can see in the code there are no part for generate cookie or some form of retaining user information for the client to attach next request afterward.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My colleagues built a wrapper around an oauth2 implementation which we want to use internally to authenticate us. The system knows about the clients that want to auhtenticate through the api. But I do agree with you. It seems a bit weird that I have to authenticate someone through their system in order for them to use my system. Also its basically just for a specific endpoint where I will get data on a frequent level

Comment: If the case was so, then it's considerable case. But as you said that system was also oauth2, so how about using multiple authorization policy ? and for that specific endpoint, just put an annotation there, then the whole authentication process would go through your policy, which can benefit from that system `.wellknow` endpoint